# Any other ways to make multiple sites on one server use different PHP versions?

Tags: server, apache2, php

I recently upgraded the PHP version on 3 production servers to 7.4, along with MySQL and Apache2. Today we learned that one of the websites is still showing 7.2 in `phpinfo()`, despite `php -v` showing 7.4 at the CLI. I checked the `.conf` file for the site (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.your_domain.conf`), but it doesn't show what I expected it to, namely it doesn't mention a PHP version at all. I figured there'd be something like this example:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
</FilesMatch>
```

But no, the `<FilesMatch>` section of the `.conf` file for my site says this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
               SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
```

There's no mention of the PHP version anywhere in the site `.conf` file. I was under the impression that if `SetHandler` wasn't set that the site would default to the webserver default (7.4). So what is keeping it at 7.2?

I'm kind of at a loss as to where to look now. My Google-fu is failing me. Every search I try simply tells me how to change the CLI version of PHP or set the above settings in the `VirtualHost` section of the individual site config using `SetHandler`. Nothing that seems to apply to my situation unless I'm missing something. Any ideas? Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: What is the third line (Server API) of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`? I suppose it is *Apache 2.0 Handler* which means the Apache web server uses PHP module instead of *FPM/FastCGI* service to handling the PHP files. In that case you need to `sudo a2dismod php7.2`, then `sudo a2enmod php7.4` and finally `sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`. Otherwise you must setup Apache2 to work with FPM and change the `VH.conf` file.

Comment: If the module is not installed: `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.4`.